# how to get a dictionary out of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to get a dictionary out of a list . First I had a list of lists and with the code below I got a list from the list of lists :

```
y_table = [["Account Manager", "Name", "BP", "Contact", "Quote Name", "Type", "Status", "Total"],
            ["bubble", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill"],
            ["rose", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill"],
            ["purple", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill"],
            ["dark", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill"],
            ["star", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill"],
            ["asmr", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill"],]

flat_list = []
for sublist in my_table:
    for item in sublist:
        flat_list.append(item)
print(flat_list)
```

now my list of lists looks like this :

```
['Account Manager', 'Name', 'BP', 'Contact', 'Quote Name', 'Type', 'Status', 'Total', 'bubble', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'rose', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'purple', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'dark', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'star', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill', 'asmr', 'kwlak', '5677', 'conn', '987', 'butter', 'fish', 'fill']
```

Now I want from this list to get a dictionary which I want it to look like this at the end :

```
Table: [{'Account Manager': 'bubble', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
{'Account Manager': 'rose', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
{'Account Manager': 'purple', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
{'Account Manager': 'dark', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
{'Account Manager': 'star', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
{'Account Manager': 'asmr', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}]
```

I tried to run this code to get this dictionary but it is not working :

```
header_my_table = flat_list[0]
my_table.remove(flat_list[0])

my_table_dict = dict(zip(header_my_table, flat_list))

print(my_table_dict)
```

Comment: You are calling the output you want a dictionary but showing us a list of dict instead. That's confusing.

Comment: if you use pandas, list(pd.DataFrame(y_table[1:], columns=y_table[0]).T.to_dict().values())

Comment: sorry I've been on this so long I'm confused . I need it out as a list of dictionaries as I wrote earlier . I thought I might format it at the end after I set the dictionary as I want it . Any thought on how to get my result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's much easier to construct your desired list from `y_table` instead of flattening it. Since you want to use the first sublist as keys and the other sublists as values, you can simply iterate over `y_table[1:]` and use dict constructor on zipped pairs of `y_table[0]` and each sublist:

```
out = [dict(zip(y_table[0], lst)) for lst in y_table[1:]]
```

Output:

```
[{'Account Manager': 'bubble', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 
  'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
 {'Account Manager': 'rose', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 
  'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
 {'Account Manager': 'purple', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 
  'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
 {'Account Manager': 'dark', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 
  'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
 {'Account Manager': 'star', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 
  'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}, 
 {'Account Manager': 'asmr', 'Name': 'kwlak', 'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 
  'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill'}]
```

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work in my code ...so y_table is my_table but I do not understand what lst is in my code :(

Comment: @Andy `lst` just references each of the sublists in `y_table[1:]`

Comment: :( still not working...

Comment: it woooorked :D thaaank youuu so much ! I tried to use the zip function before but clearlky not correct . This helped me a lot :) Thanks a milion :)